# Simplify Gamma function given integer variables

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to simplify the following

```
Gamma[1 + d - k]
```

given the constraint that `1 + d - k` is a positive integer. I have tried using

```
FullSimplify[Gamma[1 + d - k], {1 + d - k ∈ Integers, 1 + d - k > 0}]
```

However, this simply returns `Gamma[1 + d - k]`. I am expecting `(d - k)!` to be returned. Is there another way to simplify this expression with Mathematica?

Comment: You may have to use `Gamma[1 + d - k] /. Gamma[x_] :> Factorial[x - 1]`.

Comment: The easiest way is `Gamma[1 + d - k] /. Gamma[x_] :> (x - 1)!` Note that this relationship holds for all x, i.e., `Gamma[x] == (x - 1)! // FullSimplify` evaluates to `True`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there

```
$Version
(* 12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 13, 2020) *)

FullSimplify[Gamma[1+ d - k],Element[d,Integers] && Element[k,Integers] && 1+d-k > 0]
(* (d-k)! *)
```